# How to check if two same values in 2 lists return true using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists of pixel coordinates

```py
(confirmed pixel[(60, 176), (60, 174), (63, 163), (61, 176)] & 
white_pixel [(64, 178), (60, 174), (61, 176)])
```

I want to compare them both, and if any same values are found such as *(61, 176)* and 
*(60, 174)*, it will return **True**, meaning at least one value needs to match.

How can I do this in this *if* statement?

confirmed_pixel == white_pixel doesn't work as *all* the values in both lists need to be the same for it to return true

```
if confirmed_pixel == white_pixel and len(confirmed_pixel) != 0 and len(white_pixel) != 0:
    print("True")
    continue
```

Comment: You could do this with a loop.

Comment: You have two `list` of `tuples`. Compare each `tuple` from the 1st `list` with all other `tuples` from the second `list` using `loop`. You can `print` `True` in case of equality.

Comment: Hello Cytex, welcome to SO. It is easy to find duplicates of your problem on SO using google search - I used this: `python check if two lists share elements` as google query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) for that, that's the only way to test intersections efficiently. :

```
confirmed = [(60, 176), (60, 174), (63, 163), (61, 176)]
white = [(64, 178), (60, 174), (61, 176)]
```

To get the intersection:

```
print(set(confirmed).intersection(white))
# {(60, 174), (61, 176)}
```

To get `True` or `False`, just cast the resulting set to a `bool`: empty sets are False, non-empty ones will be True:

```
print(bool(set(confirmed).intersection(white)))
# True
```

Another example, with empty intersection:

```
confirmed = [(60, 176), (600, 174), (63, 163), (6100, 176)]
white = [(64, 178), (60, 174), (61, 176)]


print(set(confirmed).intersection(white))
# set()
print(bool(set(confirmed).intersection(white)))
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the expected work for you

```
if any([x==y for x in confirmed_pixel for y in white_pixel]):
    return True
```